# Excel VBA using Double to do math on numbers with 3 decimal places

Tags: excel, math, double

I am using Excel 2010
I am having trouble with math in some VBA code. I am adding and subtracting some figures in a column according to some criteria and when I do this with figures entered containing 3 decimal places the results are not what I expect.

So, I add 4032.258 + 773.994, which yields 4806.252; but when I use an if statement to test whether there is sufficient (without going negative – it should =0) to take 4806.252 from that total, I don’t get Zero, I get something akin to '-9.09494701772928E-13'.

iQty holds the total of the sum of 4032.258 + 773.994 – nQty holds the amount 4806.252

My If statement looks like this;
If iQty >= nQty Then    ' I expect=TRUE, enough or more than enough

The code above rejects the comparison.

I am using Double's as my variables to hold the numbers as I add and subtract them, I suspect this is the issue but am not sure what to use instead.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to how floating-point numbers are stored and calculated in Excel ( [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)). Long story ([explained by Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/troubleshooting-data-types)) short use round function to some precision:

```
If Round(iQty,5) >= Round(nQty,5) Then
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reading and replying so promptly. First look says that will work fine. So Double is the way to go, but need to do some rounding for comparisons ? Thanks again.

Comment: Either that or another solution explained in 3rd link: To compare floating-point quantities
1. Calculate the absolute value of their difference by using the Abs method of the Math class in the System namespace.
2. Determine an acceptable maximum difference, such that you can consider the two quantities to be equal for practical purposes if their difference is no larger.
3. Compare the absolute value of the difference to the acceptable difference.